# Looking for more efficient VBA to Move data from Teradata to Excel

Tags: beginner, vba, excel

I have a simple macro moving data from Teradata to Excel. The process normally takes me 10 minutes to perform manually, however the macro can run for hours sometimes. This is making the macro seems counterproductive. But I still want to give it a chance.

Manually, I would just simply paste the sql to teradata, and copy/paste the results to Excel. This takes about 10 mins including the teradata run time.

Can someone suggest any ways to improve the performance? I'm still quite new to macros, so using simple language would be very much appreciated.

Edit - Should I put all the sql codes in cell A1 instead of A1-A44? (It didn't seem to work).

```
Option Explicit
Global glbUN As String
Global glbPWD As String
Global cnEDW As ADODB.Connection

Sub RefreshData()

Call Open_EDWDatabase
DoEvents    
 
 Call BuildCode
  DoEvents

End Sub

Public Sub Open_EDWDatabase()

Set cnEDW = New ADODB.Connection
If glbUN = "" Or glbPWD = "" Then
    'Open login screen and center the form for people with 2 monitors
    UserForm1.StartUpPosition = 0
    UserForm1.Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * UserForm1.Width)
    UserForm1.Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * UserForm1.Height)
    UserForm1.Show 1
End If

cnEDW.ConnectionString = "Driver={Teradata};Persist Security Info=False;User ID=" & glbUN & ";Pwd=" & glbPWD & ";Data Source=teradata_PRD"
cnEDW.Open

End Sub
Public Sub Close_EDWDatabase()

cnEDW.Close
Set cnEDW = Nothing

End Sub

Sub BuildCode()

 Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim LastLineofSQL As Long
Dim LastLineofSQL2 As Long
Dim strQry As String
Dim strQry2 As String
Dim x, y As Long
Dim OutputAddress As String
Dim iCol As Long

LastLineofSQL = 44

strQry = ""


Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = cnEDW
cmd.CommandTimeout = 20000000


For x = 1 To LastLineofSQL
        strQry = strQry + Sheets("Codes").Cells(x, 1).Value
   
    If InStr(strQry, ";") <> 0 Then
        cmd.CommandText = strQry
        Set rs = cmd.Execute
                   
        If x = LastLineofSQL Then

            Sheets("Data").Range("B2").CopyFromRecordset rs
        End If
        strQry = ""
        DoEvents
    Else
        If Right$(strQry, 2) <> vbCrLf Then
            strQry = strQry + vbCrLf
        End If
    End If
Next x

        
End Sub
```

Here's the SQL for Teradata -

```
 SELECT 
    Trim(pln_id) AS pln_id
    ,Trim(lob) AS line_of_bus
    ,eom
    ,Trim(Extract(YEAR From eom)) AS "year"
    ,Trim(pln_network) AS ACA_network
    ,Trim(prod_typ_cd) AS prod_type
    ,Trim(aca_metal) AS ACA_metal
    ,Trim(aca_exchange_ind) AS ACA_exchange_ind
    ,Trim(pln_rating_area) AS rating_area_name
    ,Trim(risk_bucket) AS risk_bucket
    ,Trim(hcc_cnt) AS hcc_cnt
    ,Trim(duration) AS duration
    ,Cast(Sum(CASE WHEN members <> 0 THEN age ELSE 0 END) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS total_age
    ,Cast(Sum(CASE WHEN members <> 0 AND dxcgEZ_risk_score IS NOT NULL THEN age_factor ELSE 0 END) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS total_age_fctr
    ,Cast(Sum(risk_adj) AS DECIMAL(18,4)) AS risk_adj
    ,Cast(Sum(comp_reins) AS DECIMAL(18,4)) AS comp_reins
    ,Sum(contracts) AS contracts
    ,Sum(members) AS members
    ,Sum(premium) AS premium
    ,Sum(csr_pd) AS csr_payment
    ,Sum(csr_ibnp) AS csr_ibnp_payment
    ,Sum(capitation) AS capitation
    ,Cast(Sum(inc_clms) AS DECIMAL(18,4)) AS inc_clms
    ,Cast(Sum(inc_paid_clms) AS DECIMAL(18,4)) AS inc_paid_clms
    ,Cast(Sum(inc_clms_med) AS DECIMAL(18,4)) AS inc_clms_med
    ,Cast(Sum(inc_paid_clms_med) AS DECIMAL(18,4)) AS inc_paid_clms_med
    ,Cast(Sum(inc_clms_rx) AS DECIMAL(18,4)) AS inc_clms_rx
    ,Cast(Sum(inc_paid_clms_rx) AS DECIMAL(18,4)) AS inc_paid_clms_rx
    ,Cast(Sum(CASE WHEN members <> 0 THEN dxcgEZ_risk_score ELSE 0 END) AS DECIMAL(18,4)) AS total_risk_score
    ,Sum(CASE WHEN dxcgEZ_risk_score IS NOT NULL AND members <> 0 THEN members ELSE 0 END) AS mbrs_w_risk
    ,Cast(Sum(rebates) AS DECIMAL(18,4)) AS  total_rebates

FROM
    Table1
     
    WHERE premium IS NOT NULL
    AND eom >=  (SELECT Add_Months(Max(eom) + 1, -39) - 1  FROM   Table1 ) 
    And eom  <= (SELECT Add_Months(Max(eom) + 1, -1) - 1  FROM   Table1 ) 

    
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12;
```

Comment: Your title could apply to basically every post. Based on this site's rules, the name should state what the code does. That you are especially interested in performance tips would go into the text itself. This really helps reviewers to discover which posts they want to review. So, could you please edit this post's title so that it reflects what the code does?

Comment: Hours as opposed to minutes is quite stark, especially for a language like VBA which is designed to help automate manual tasks (Visual Basic for Applications). I would be interested to hear what your usual manual process would be, to see if that sheds any light on the performance issues - perhaps you could edit your question with a brief description?

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I have edited the post. Thanks!

Comment: @Pumpkin Right, so if I understand correctly, your code loops through `A1:A44` concatenating the values into a query string `strQry = strQry + [...]`. If the current query string terminates: `InStr(strQry, ";")` then execute it, and if it's the last query then copy the results to the sheet. Is that right? I think the slowness is likely to be coming from executing the SQL line by line like this, although writing to the sheet may be slow too; if you want some help diagnosing this I think you'll need to show the SQL statement you execute as well as what your DB looks like - context is everything!

Comment: Hi Greedo, Yes, you're right ! And the sql statement is very simple, it just simply pulls different fields from a table in Teradata without any joins. That normally takes about 20 seconds for Teradata to run. So that piece is probably not an issue. So are you saying that I should put the whole sql query in cell A1 instead of A1-A44?

Comment: The question that I think needs to be answered first is, how many times is the line `Set rs = cmd.Execute` being executed. AFAICT it's only being called once. I would guess that to be the real bottleneck; concatenating 44 strings, even while reading them via the Excel Automation API, doesn't seem to me to be the issue here. We really need to see the SQL statement.

Comment: Ok. I have added the sql statement. Thank you!

Comment: @ZevSpitz I have added the sql statement. I have also tried to whole the whole sql statement in cell A1, but that didn't help.

Comment: (NB -- I know nothing about Teradata.) Next question: The same query takes about 20 seconds to run directly against Teradata. How have you run the query that it only takes 20 seconds? // It would seem as though something in the communication between VBA and Teradata is the issue, either the programming layers of COM, VBA, Excel Automation; or the sheer volume of data returned. Is there some kind of networking involved?