# Run Teradata using Excel VBA

Tags: performance, vba

I have a simple macro moving data from Teradata to Excel. The process normally takes me 10 minutes to perform manually, however the macro can run for hours sometimes. This is making the macro seems counterproductive. But I still want to give it a chance.

Manually, I would just simply paste the sql to teradata, and copy/paste the results to Excel. This takes about 10 mins including the teradata run time.

Can someone suggest any ways to improve the performance? I'm still quite new to macros, so using simple language would be very much appreciated.

```
Option Explicit
Global glbUN As String
Global glbPWD As String
Global cnEDW As ADODB.Connection

Sub RefreshData()

Call Open_EDWDatabase
DoEvents    
 
 Call BuildCode
  DoEvents

End Sub

Public Sub Open_EDWDatabase()

Set cnEDW = New ADODB.Connection
If glbUN = "" Or glbPWD = "" Then
    'Open login screen and center the form for people with 2 monitors
    UserForm1.StartUpPosition = 0
    UserForm1.Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * UserForm1.Width)
    UserForm1.Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * UserForm1.Height)
    UserForm1.Show 1
End If

cnEDW.ConnectionString = "Driver={Teradata};Persist Security Info=False;User ID=" & glbUN & ";Pwd=" & glbPWD & ";Data Source=teradata_PRD"
cnEDW.Open

End Sub
Public Sub Close_EDWDatabase()

cnEDW.Close
Set cnEDW = Nothing

End Sub

Sub BuildCode()

 Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim LastLineofSQL As Long
Dim LastLineofSQL2 As Long
Dim strQry As String
Dim strQry2 As String
Dim x, y As Long
Dim OutputAddress As String
Dim iCol As Long

LastLineofSQL = 44

strQry = ""


Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = cnEDW
cmd.CommandTimeout = 20000000


For x = 1 To LastLineofSQL
        strQry = strQry + Sheets("Codes").Cells(x, 1).Value
   
    If InStr(strQry, ";") <> 0 Then
        cmd.CommandText = strQry
        Set rs = cmd.Execute
                   
        If x = LastLineofSQL Then

            Sheets("Data").Range("B2").CopyFromRecordset rs
        End If
        strQry = ""
        DoEvents
    Else
        If Right$(strQry, 2) <> vbCrLf Then
            strQry = strQry + vbCrLf
        End If
    End If
Next x

        
End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Looking for more efficient VBA to Move data from Teradata to Excel](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/243493/looking-for-more-efficient-vba-to-move-data-from-teradata-to-excel)

Comment: Feel free to edit the original post to bump it back onto the front page, but please do not post duplicates.